# How does Dictionary<string, object> know the type of the value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, json.net, .net-4.5

Consider this code:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

Dictionary<string,object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

List<string> parameters = new List<string>{"Car", "Truck", "Van"};

foreach (var p in parameters)
{
    JToken token = obj.SelectToken(string.Format("$.results[?(@.paramName == '{0}')]['value']", p));
    dict[p] = token.Value<object>();
}

string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

where `json` contains, in part:

```
{
    "paramName": "Car",
    "value": 68.107
},
{
    "paramName": "Truck",
    "value": 48.451
},
{
    "paramName": "Van",
    "value": 798300
}
```

While debugging this, I inspected the dictionary and found the values were not of type `object` but actual numeric types like `integer` and `float`. Since the dictionary was declared as `Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();` I expected the values to be of type `object` and that I would need to cast them upon use.

The JSON output string is `{"Car":68.107,"Truck":48.451,"Van":798300}`.

How does the dictionary know the type of the value and why do I get the actual type instead of the base type `object`?

Comment: You're confusing runtime type and compile-time type.  You do need to cast.

Comment: Debugger has sufficient *runtime* information about a type you're questioning, hence is able to provide to you smooth user experience. The real type is still `object` as you would expect it to be.

Comment: the NewtonSoft.Json framework interprets the value type based on JSON schema

Comment: @Nkosi There's no schema here

Comment: @DavidG `"value": 68.107` is a `float`, `"value": "68.107"` is a `String`

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, but that's not a schema, that's just the converter figuring out what to do with the string inside the JSON snippet.

Comment: @DavidG and is that not based on default schema for JSON?

Comment: @Nkosi I don't really know what you mean by "default schema"

Comment: @DavidG then I guess I may be using the wrong term. JSON data type specifications would probably better explain what I meant.

Comment: @Nkosi Ah yes, JSON schema is a very different thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

this takes an object, which then figures out the type, and stores it accordingly.

Therefore for each item in the dictionary entry. it first checks the type and then deserializes it according to its type.

If you wanted to use the object outside of JSON, you would have to check yourself with something like

```
var o = dict["Car"];

if(o is int) return (int)o; // or whatever you want to do with an int
if(o is decimal) return (decimal)o; // or whatever you want to do with an decimal
```

Comment: You mean serializes it according to its type. When it deserializes it is guessing based on the serialized value, as at that point it has no type information.

Comment: @wllmsaccnt yes, ofcourse, although you could help it by specifying `JsonConvert.Deserialize<string, double>(json)`

Comment: It's very odd that JSON.Net deserializes it in anything but string. It may use some heuristics, but that doesn't make any big sense, just treat all values as strings (JSON is a string format) and you're golden. It seems that it is working so because it should be able to parse inner object so it is doing it eagerly, and tries to determine most convenient type.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect an instance in the debugger, the debugger just shows you the output of the `.ToString()` for the item. Run the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "One", "1" }, { "Two", 2 },
                { "Three", 3.0 }, { "Four", new Person() },
                { "Five", new SimplePerson() },

            };
            foreach (var thisItem in dic)
            {
                // thisItem.Value will show "1", 2, 3, "Test" 
                // and ConsoleApplication1.SimplePerson
                Console.WriteLine($"{ thisItem.Key } : { thisItem.Value }");
            }

            var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
        }
    }

    public class SimplePerson
    {

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

When you hover over the `this.Value`, it will show the result of `ToString()`. So it will show the following:

```
"1"
2
3
"Test" // since Person class overrides the ToString()
// since by default when ToString() is called it will print out the object.
ConsoleApplication1.SimplePerson
```

---

**Serialization**

For serialization, it will produce the following:

```
{
    "One": "1",
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3.0,
    "Four": {

    },
    "Five": {

    }
}
```

They are all boxed as `object` types but when the underlying type is whatever the type is. So in our case `String",`Int`,`Double`,`Person`and`SimplePerson`. Therefore, during serialization it is unboxed.